# Can I populate the whole directory with Node.js Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

so i probably phrased it really bad, but I am stuck right now. I am trying to create an Instagram-like site and I've encountered a problem. I have a Posts Schema where i store all the made posts, i display them on the home page by using posts.forEach, how can I insert the comment Schema into the home page get route so that there i could loop through all the posts and for each one individually loop through all the comments? I am really new here I dont really know how to phrase this question, but I hope you will get my point right. Huge thanks in advance!

```
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    //get all posts from db
    posts.find({}, function(err, allPosts){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.render("home", {posts: allPosts});
        }
    });
});
```

```
<% posts.forEach(function(posts){ %>
    <div class="ui card" style="margin: 4% 20%;float: none;margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="right floated meta">Time</div>
            <img class="ui avatar image" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/person-icon-260nw-282598823.jpg"> Elliot
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="<%= posts.image %>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
                <span class="right floated">
                  <i class="heart outline like icon"></i>
                  Likes
                </span>
                <i class="comment icon"></i>
                Comments
              </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
            <p class="card-text"><%= posts.description %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="extra content">
            <div class="ui large transparent left icon input">
                <i class="heart outline icon"></i>
                <input type="text" class="card-input" placeholder="Add Comment...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }) %>
```

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [
        {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "Comment"
        }
     ]
});
```

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: String
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to populate like this:

```
app.get("/", async function(req,res){
    //get all posts from db
    const allPosts = await posts.find({}).populate('comments');
    res.render("home", {posts: allPosts});
});
```

Use try-catch to handle error (promise rejection).